# spawning spheres in gazebo as simulated point cloud

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I'm working on spawning spheres in gazebo to simulate point clouds for probabilities.  I have been able to spawn objects with the command line,

rosrun gazebo spawn_model -file /opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/objects/simple_box.urdf -urdf -x 1.18 -y .91 -z 1.549 -model box1

but it seems when spawning objects this way you can't make them static, or resize the objects.

Is there a way to spawn objects with the ability to make them unaffected by gravity and resize-able?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39693/spawning-spheres-in-gazebo-as-simulated-point-cloud/) by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 325 on 2012-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can make a static object .model file and just spawn that. For example, a static box model looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<model:physical name="small_box_model">
<!--  <xyz>   0.835  -0.55   0.5</xyz>
  <rpy>   0.0    0.0    30.0</rpy>-->
  <static>true</static>
  <body:box name="small_box_body">
    <geom:box name="small_box_geom">
      <kp>100000000.0</kp>
      <kd>0.1</kd>
      <mesh>default</mesh>
      <size>0.1 0.1 0.1</size>
      <mass> 0.05</mass>
      <visual>
        <size> 0.1 0.1 0.1</size>
        <material>Gazebo/Red</material>
        <mesh>unit_box</mesh>
      </visual>
    </geom:box>
  </body:box>
</model:physical>
```

By changing the 'static' tag to false, you'll get a object affected by gravity and colliding with other objects. I'm not sure about the scaling of a sphere though, I had some problems with that before (especially with the visuals getting scaled, but the collision model staying at 1m radius).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0